Number of $k$-element linearly equivalence classes of ${\mathbb{F}_2}^4$
Work over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_2 = \{0, 1\}$. Say that two sets $S , T \subseteq {\mathbb{F}_2}^4$ are linearly equivalent if there exists an invertible $4 \times 4$ matrix $A$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$ such that $A \cdot S = T$, where $A \cdot S = \{Ax \in {\mathbb{F}_2}^4 : \, x \in S\}$. For each $k = 0, 1, 2, \dots, 16$, how many equivalence classes of $k$-element subsets of ${\mathbb{F}_2}^4$ are there?
First, I would like to thank ancient mathematician and Jyrki Lahtonen for their contributes to my corresponding question for ${\mathbb{F}_2}^3$. What follows below is partly based on their ideas. Let $a(k)$ be the number of equivalence classes of $k$-element subsets of ${\mathbb{F}_2}^4$. Two linearly equivalent subsets either both contain the zero vector $0$ or both do not contain $0$. So let $a_0(k)$ be the number of equivalence classes of $k$-element subsets of ${\mathbb{F}_2}^4$ that contain $0$, and let $a_-(k)$ be the number of equivalence classes of $k$-element subsets of ${\mathbb{F}_2}^4$ that do not contain $0$. Then
$$a(k) = a_0(k) + a_-(k).$$
Given a $(k + 1)$-element subset that contains $0$, removing the zero vctor yields a $k$-element subset that does not contain $0$. Thus $a_0(k + 1) = a_-(k)$ for $0 \le k < 16$. Given a $k$-element subset $S \subseteq {\mathbb{F}_2}^4$ that contains $0$, its complement ${\mathbb{F}_2}^4 \setminus S$ is a $(2^4 - k) = (16 - k)$-element subset that does not contain $0$. Thus $a_0(k) = a_-(16 - k)$. Similarly, $a_-(k) = a_0(16 - k)$. Also $a_-(0) = a_-(1) = a_2(2) = 1$. And $a_-(3) = 2$, with representatives $\{(1, 0, 0,0), (0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1, 0)\}$ and $\{(1, 0, 0,0), (0, 1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0, 0)\}$. So we have:
\begin{array}{|c|cc|c|}
\hline
k & a_0(k) & a_-(k) & a(k) \\ \hline
0 & 0      & 1      & 1\\ \hline
1 & 1      & 1      & 2\\ \hline
2 & 1      & 1      & 2\\ \hline
3 & 1      & 2      & 3 \\ \hline
4 & 2      & x      & \\ \hline
5 & x      & y     & \\ \hline
6 & y      & z      & \\ \hline
7 & z      & w      & \\ \hline
8 & w      & w      & \\ \hline
\end{array}
and the other half of the table can be obtained by "reflection". So I am left to determine 4 quantities $x, y, z, w$.

When $k=4$ the work on the 3-dimensional version still gives you everything. The results there tell us that there are four equivalence classes of quartets $S$ such that $S$ is contained in a given 3-dimensional subspace $V$. The group $G=GL_4(\Bbb{F}_2)$ acts transitively on the set of such subspaces. Furthermore, the stabilizer of $Stab_G(V)$ acts on $V$ in the same way as $GL_3(\Bbb{F}_2)$ acted in that earlier problem. In addition, there is a single equivalence class of linearly independent quartets. Thus $a(4)=5$.

It gets progressively hairier. I would try and classify them by the dimensions of their linear and affine spans, but cannot tell how easy it will be to carry out such a program.

When $k = 5$, is it clear how many classes of nonzero quintets span $F_2^4$?

Is there exactly one quintet, up to linear equivalence, of nonzero vectors that spans $F_2^4$?

or are there 4 such inequivalent spanning nonzero quintets, namely {i, j, k, l, i + j}, {i, j, k, l, i + j + k}, {i, j, k, l, i + j + k + l}, where {i, j, k, l} is the standard basis?

I keep wanting to use the concept of an $m$-flat (= a coset of an $m$-dimensional subspace) simply because a non-singular linear transformation maps an $m$-flat to another. So ${0,i,j,i+j}$ is a 2-d subspace (and also a $2$-flat), ${k,k+i,k+j,k+i+j}$ is a 2-flat etc. The group acts on an $m$-flat as the $m$-dimensional general linear group, if the flat is a subspace, and as the corresponding affine group if it's not. Your earlier question classifies 5-tets contained in a 3d-subspace.  A quintet may also be contained in a 3-flat that is not a subspace.

(cont'd) Such a 3-flat is the complement of 3-d subspace. in that case the earlier work still helps, but an $m$-flat has no special point (= the zero vector). A quintet may be the union of a 2-flat and a singleton. Such a quintet may or may not be contained in  3d-subspace etc. Keeping track of all that feels like juggling several balls at once because care is required to keep the cases independent...

two linearly equivalent sets have isomorphic lattice of flats.

are ${i, j, k, l, i +j}$ and ${i, j, k, l, i + j + k}$ linearly equivalent?

No. ${i,j,k,\ell,i+j+k}$ contains the 2-flat ${i,j,k,i+j+k}$, but the other quintet does not contain a 2-flat. A 2-flat is just a subset of three vectors and the sum of all three of them.

Equivalently. When there are two pairs of vectors with the same difference (that is, two parallel lines or parallel 1-flats), then together they form a 2-flat. OTOH, a 2-flat can be partitioned into a union of two parallel 1-flats in three different ways.

So there are 3 inequivalent quintets of nonzero vectors that span ${\mathbb{F}_2}^4$, namely ${i, j, k, l, i + j}$, ${i, j, k, l, i + j + k}$ and ${i, j, k, l, i + j +k + l}$. Since (the number of inequivalent quintets of nonzero vectors whose linear span is at most $3$-dimensional) is equal to (the number of $(2^3 - 5) = 3$-tets of inequivalent vectors that contain the zero vector and whose linear span is at most $3$-dimensional) is equal to (the number of inequivalent pairs of nonzero vectors in ${\mathbb{F}2}^3$) is equal to $1$, so $a-(5) = 3 + 1 = 4$.

A bit too much juggling for me to check that now :-). You can check your own work by counting all the quintets in a class by identifying the stabilizer subgroup of a representative, then using orbit-stabilizer, and as the check verify that the total is $\binom{16}5$. Not trivial, but if you need to be sure!? I once did something similar with the Reed-Muller code $RM(5,2)$ consisting of the "span" of $3$-flats in a 5d-space. But I only needed to classify the coset leaders, and never needed to go higher than 6-tets (that was the covering radius).

if two sets induce isomorphic lattice of flats, are there two sets linearly equivalent?

I know a guy who programs very similar tasks. Your question looks easily computable and he can be interested in it, so I sent to him a letter.

thanks Alex Ravsky.

This seems super amenable to just brute force computing. Even in the $k=7$ case we're talking about ~6400 sets, being acted on by a group of size ~20k. I'd be surprised if GAP couldn't do this directly. If it's not already answered by this weekend, I'll write some hacky code to figure it out. Should be fun!

Steve, yes, do contribute your computing solution. You could you include your GAP code in your answer.

Here is an ugly, brute-force proof. There are probably some improvements and simplifications that could be made on it.
I show below that $x=3,y=4,z=5,w=6$. I do this by giving a complete description
of the sets $A^{-}(k)$ for $5 \leq k \leq 8$.
Given a $k$-element set $X \subseteq ({\mathbb{F}}_2) ^4 \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace$, and a fixed enumeration $X=\lbrace x_1,\ldots,x_k\rbrace$ of $X$, for $j\in[|3..k|]$ define $z_j(x_1,\ldots,x_k)$ as the number
of subsets $I\subseteq [|1..k|]$ satisfying $|I|=j$ and  $\sum_{i\in I}x_i=0$. This is clearly independent of the enumeration chosen, so we may denote this number
by $z_j(X)$. Next, define the signature $z(X)$ of $X$ as the uple $(z_3(X),z_4(X),\ldots,z_k(X))$. Then, linearly equivalent subsets have the same signature.
It will follow from the results below that for $5 \leq k \leq 8$, the converse is also true : two sets with identical signature are linearly equivalent, and we can assign a pattern to each signature such that a set with that signature can always be written is a way that matches that pattern (though of course the pattern is usually nonunique and there are many linearly equivalent patterns : for example the patterns $\lbrace v_1,v_2,v_3,v_1+v_2\rbrace$ and $\lbrace v_1,v_2,v_3,v_1+v_3\rbrace$ are trivially linearly equivalent).
In the statements below, for convenience we use the shorthand $b_r$ for $v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_r$. For a given vector $v$ written as a sum $v=\sum_{i\in I} v_i$, we define the length of $v$ to be cardinality $|I|$ of $I$.
Theorem 1. A $4$-element set $X \subseteq ({\mathbb{F}}_2) ^4 \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ is in exactly one of the cases enumerated below :
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textrm{Name of pattern} & \textrm{Pattern} & \textrm{Signature} \\ \hline
P(4,1) & b_4             & (0,0)      \\ \hline
P(4,2) & b_3,v_1+v_2     & (1,0)      \\ \hline
P(4,3) & b_3,v_1+v_2+v_3 & (0,1)      \\ \hline
\end{array}
Theorem 2. A $5$-element set $X \subseteq ({\mathbb{F}}_2) ^4 \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ is in exactly one of the cases enumerated below :
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textrm{Name of pattern} & \textrm{Pattern} & \textrm{Signature}    \\ \hline
P(5,1) & b_4,v_1+v_2         & (1,0,0)      \\ \hline
P(5,2) & b_4,v_1+v_2+v_3     & (0,1,0)      \\ \hline
P(5,3) & b_4,v_1+v_2+v_3+v_4 & (0,0,1)      \\ \hline
P(5,4) & b_3,v_1+v_2,v_1+v_3 & (2,1,0)      \\ \hline
\end{array}
Theorem 3. A $6$-element set $X \subseteq ({\mathbb{F}}_2) ^4 \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ is in exactly one of the cases enumerated below :
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textrm{Name of pattern} & \textrm{Pattern} & \textrm{Signature}    \\ \hline
P(6,1) & b_4,v_1+v_2,v_1+v_3         & (2,1,0,0)      \\ \hline
P(6,2) & b_4,v_1+v_2,v_3+v_4         & (2,0,0,1)      \\ \hline
P(6,3) & b_4,v_1+v_2,v_1+v_3+v_4     & (1,1,1,0)      \\ \hline
P(6,4) & b_4,v_1+v_2+v_3,v_1+v_2+v_4 & (0,3,0,0)      \\ \hline
P(6,5) & b_3,v_1+v_2,v_1+v_3,v_2+v_3 & (4,3,0,0)      \\ \hline
\end{array}
Theorem 4. A $7$-element set $X \subseteq ({\mathbb{F}}_2) ^4 \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ is in exactly one of the cases enumerated below :
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textrm{Name of pattern} & \textrm{Pattern} & \textrm{Signature}    \\ \hline
P(7,1) & b_4,v_1+v_2,v_1+v_3,v_2+v_3             & (4,3,0,0,0)      \\ \hline
P(7,2) & b_4,v_1+v_2,v_1+v_3,v_1+v_4             & (3,3,0,0,1)      \\ \hline
P(7,3) & b_4,v_1+v_2,v_1+v_3,v_2+v_4             & (3,2,1,1,0)      \\ \hline
P(7,4) & b_4,v_1+v_2,v_1+v_3,v_2+v_3+v_4         & (2,3,2,0,0)      \\ \hline
P(7,5) & b_4,v_1+v_2+v_3,v_1+v_2+v_4,v_1+v_3+v_4 & (0,7,0,0,0)      \\ \hline
P(7,6) & b_3,v_1+v_2,v_1+v_3,v_2+v_3,v_1+v_2+v_3 & (7,7,0,0,1)      \\ \hline
\end{array}
Here I will detail only the proof of theorem 4, as the proofs of the other theorems are similar and simpler.
Proof of theorem 4. Let $X \subseteq ({\mathbb{F}}_2) ^4 \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ be a $7$-element set. First of all, if $X$ has rank $\lt 4$, then
cardinality considerations suffice to show that $X$ must be a full $3$-dimensional subspace except $0$, so that we are in case $P(7,6)$. We can therefore assume
without loss that $X$ has rank $4$. It then contains four linearly independent vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4$.
Suppose that $X$ does not contain any $v_i+v_j$ $(i \lt j)$. Let $s=v_1+v_2+v_3+v_4$. If $s\not\in X$, then
$X'=X\setminus \lbrace  v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4 \rbrace$ must be of the form $\lbrace s-v_i,s-v_j,s-v_k\rbrace$ (where $s=v_1+v_2+v_3+v_4$) for indices $1 \leq i \lt j \lt k \leq 4$. By permuting the $v_i$'s we may assume that $(i,j,k)=(2,3,4)$, so that $P(7,5)$ holds, and we are therefore done in this case. If, on the other hand, $s\in X$, then $=X\setminus \lbrace  v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,s \rbrace$ consists of two elements of length $3$, say $v_1+v_2+v_3$ and $v_1+v_2+v_4$. Then  $$X=b_4 \cup \lbrace v_1+v_2+v_3,v_1+v_2+v_4,s\rbrace=$$ $$\lbrace w_1,w_2,w_3,w_4,w_1+w_2,w_1+w_3,w_2+w_3+w_4\rbrace,$$ where we put $w_1=v_1+v_2,w_2=v_1,w_3=v_3,w_4=v_4$, so that we are in case $P(7,4)$, and we are done in this case also. We may therefore assume that $X$ has the following property (Q) : if $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4$ is a basis included in $X$, then $X$ contains at least one vector of the form $v_i+v_j$ $(i \lt j)$. We will use (Q) several times throughout this proof, and every time we will use it, there will be sufficient symmetry to assume that $v_1+v_2\in X$ without loss.
Suppose, now, that the sum of the elements in $X$ is zero. We distinguish two sub-cases in this case, according to whether $X$ contains a vector of length $3$ or not. Assume first that $X$ contains a vector $t$ of length $3$, i.e. one of $t_1=v_2+v_3+v_4, t_2=v_1+v_3+v_4, t_3=v_1+v_2+v_4, t_4=v_1+v_2+v_3$. Because $X$ has sum $0$, the remaining element of $X$, the one that we have not named yet, is $v_3+v_4+t$. This element must be distinct from $v_1$ or $v_2$, so $t\not\in\lbrace t_1,t_2\rbrace$ and hence $$X=b_4 \cup \lbrace v_1+v_2,v_1+v_2+v_3,v_1+v_2+v_4\rbrace=$$ $$\lbrace w_1,w_2,w_3,w_4,w_1+w_2,w_1+w_3,w_1+w_4\rbrace,$$ where we put $w_1=v_1+v_2,w_2=v_1,w_3=v_3,w_4=v_4$, so that we are in case $P(7,2)$. If, on the other hand, $X$ contains no vector of length $3$, then $X'=X\setminus \lbrace v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_1+v_2\rbrace$ consists of two vectors of lengths $2$, whose total sum is $v_3+v_4$. This forces $X'=\lbrace v_i+v_3,v_i+v_4 \rbrace$ for some $i\in \lbrace 1,2\rbrace$. Exchanging $v_1$ and $v_2$ if necessary, we are then in case $P(7,2)$ again. The upshot of this paragraph is therefore that $P(7,2)$ holds whenever the sum of $X$ is zero. We henceforth assume without loss that the sum of $X$ is nonzero.
Suppose now that some six-element subset $Z \subseteq X$ sums to zero. Denote by $\xi$ the unique element in $X \setminus Z$. If $\xi=v_3$, then $X$ can be written $X=\lbrace v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_1+v_2 \rbrace \cup X'$, where $X'=\lbrace t, v_4 + t \rbrace$ for some $t$. Because the seven elements in $X$ are distinct, there are only three possibilities for $X'$, namely (a) $X'=\lbrace v_1+v_3, v_1 + v_3 + v_4 \rbrace$ or (b) $X'=\lbrace v_2+v_3, v_2 + v_3 + v_4 \rbrace$ or (c) $X=\lbrace v_1+v_2+v_3, v_1 + v_2 + v_3 + v_4 \rbrace$. In case (a), the change of variables $w_1=v_1,w_2=v_1+v_3,w_3=v_2,w_4=v_4$ shows that $P(7,3)$ holds. Symmetrically (interchanging $v_1$ and $v_2$), in case (b) the change of variables $w_1=v_2,w_2=v_2+v_3,w_3=v_1,w_4=v_4$ shows that $P(7,3)$ holds. Finally, in case (c) the change of variables $w_1=v_1+v_2,w_2=v_1+v_2+v_3,w_3=v_1,w_4=v_4$ shows that $P(7,3)$ holds. We have thus finished off the case $\xi=v_3$, and the case $\xi=v_4$ is similar. If $\xi\not\in \lbrace v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_1+v_2 \rbrace$, the last element of $Z$,  the one that we have not extracted yet, must be $v_3+v_4$. The possible values for $\xi$ are then $v_1+v_3,v_2+v_4$, or $v_i+(v_3+v_4)$ with $i\in \lbrace 1, 2 \rbrace$, or $v_1+v_2+v_j$ with $j\in \lbrace 3, 4 \rbrace$, or $v_1+v_2+v_3+v_4$. Using all the symmetries we have at our disposal in this subcase (interchange of $v_1$ and $v_2$, or of  $v_3$ and $v_4$, or of $\lbrace v_1,v_2\rbrace$ and $\lbrace v_3,v_4\rbrace$), it will suffice to treat the cases (d) $\xi = v_1+v_3$, (e) $\xi = v_1+v_3+v_4$, and (f) $\xi=v_1+v_2+v_3+v_4$. Using the change of variables $w_1=v_1,w_2=v_3,w_3=v_2,w_4=v_4$ in case (d), $w_1=v_1,w_2=v_3+v_4,w_3=v_2,w_4=v_4$ in case (e), and $w_1=v_1+v_2,w_2=v_3+v_4,w_3=v_1,w_4=v_4$ in case (f), in each case we see that $P(7,3)$ holds. We are then left with the three possibilities $\xi = v_1,v_2,$ or $v_1+v_2$. The first two reduce to the last one, using interchange of $v_2$ and $v_1$. We can thus assume $\xi=v_1+v_2$. Then $X$ can be written $X=\lbrace v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_1+v_2 \rbrace \cup X'$, where $X'=\lbrace t, v_1+v_2+v_3+v_4 + t \rbrace$ for some $t$.  Because the seven elements in $X$ are distinct, there are only two possibilities for $X'$, namely $X'=\lbrace v_1+v_3, v_2 + v_4 \rbrace$ or $X'=\lbrace v_1+v_4, v_2 + v_3 \rbrace$. Now those two cases are equivalent by interchanging $v_3$ and $v_4$. So it suffices to treat the first; but $P(7,3)$ clearly holds in this case.  To conclude, we have shown that $P(7,3)$ holds whenever some $6$-element subset of $X$ has sum zero. We henceforth assume without loss that no $6$-element subset of $X$ has sum zero.
Suppose now that some five-element subset $Z \subseteq X$ sums to zero. Note that, in a ${\mathbb{F}}_2$-space of dimension $3$ (which has therefore eight elements), the sum of five distinct nonzero vectors is equal to the sum of the two nonzero vectors in the complement, and is therefore nonzero. It follows that $Z$ cannot have rank $3$, so $Z$ has rank $4$, and can be written $Z=\lbrace v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_1+v_2+v_3+v_4 \rbrace$ for some linearly independent vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4$. By (Q), we can assume without loss that $v_1+v_2\in X$. Thus we can assume $\lbrace v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_1+v_2,v_1+v_2+v_3+v_4 \rbrace \subseteq X$. Since $X$ contains no zero_sum $6$-element subset, any sum of five distinct elements of $X$ is outside $X$. In particular, $v_3+v_4,v_1+v_2+v_3$ and $v_1+v_2+v_4$ are outside $X$ since $v_3+v_4=v_1+v_2+v_3+v_4+(v_1+v_2)$, $v_1+v_2+v_3=v_1+v_2+v_4+(v_1+v_2)+(v_1+v_2+v_3+v_4)$, and $v_1+v_2+v_4=v_1+v_2+v_3+(v_1+v_2)+(v_1+v_2+v_3+v_4)$. Then  $X$ can be written $X=\lbrace v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_1+v_2,v_1+v_2+v_3+v_4,t \rbrace $, where $t$ is of one of the forms $v_i+v_j,v_i+(v_3+v_4)$ with $i\in \lbrace 1,2\rbrace$, $j\in \lbrace 3,4\rbrace$. Using all the symmetries we have at our disposal in this subcase, it all reduces to (g) $t=v_1+v_3$ or (h) $t=v_1+v_3+v_4$. Using the change variables $w_1=v_1,w_2=v_2,w_3=v_1+v_3,w_4=v_4$ in case (g), and $w_1=v_2,w_2=v_1,w_3=v_1=v_3+v_4,w_4=v_4$ in case (h), we see that $P(7,4)$ holds.  To conclude, we have shown that $P(7,4)$ holds whenever some $5$-element subset (but no $6$-element subset) of $X$ has sum zero. We henceforth assume without loss that no $5$-element subset of $X$ has sum zero.
By (Q), we can assume  $\lbrace v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_1+v_2 \rbrace \subseteq X$. Since $X$ contains no zero_sum $5$-element subset, any sum of four distinct elements of $X$ is outside $X$. In particular, $v_1+v_3+v_4=v_2+v_3+v_4+(v_1+v_2)$, $v_2+v_3+v_4=v_1+v_3+v_4+(v_1+v_2)$ and $v_1+v_2+v_3+v_4$ are all outside $X$. Similarly
$v_3+v_4=v_1+v_2+v_3+v_4+(v_1+v_2)$ is outside $X$.
Next, $X$ cannot contain both $v_1+v_2+v_3$ and $v_1+v_2+v_4$, as this would make $X$ have zero sum.  Suppose that $X$ contains exactly one of them, say
$v_1+v_2+v_3 \in X$ (since $v_3$ and $v_4$ are interchangeable at this stage). Since $X$ contains no zero_sum $5$-element subset, any sum of four distinct elements of $X$ is outside $X$. In particular, from $v_1+v_4=v_2+v_3+v_4+(v_1+v_2+v_3)$, $v_2+v_4=v_1+v_3+v_4+(v_1+v_2+v_3)$ and $v_3+v_4=v_1+v_2+v_4+(v_1+v_2+v_3)$ we see that all the $v_i+v_4$ $(1 \leq i \leq 3)$ are outside $X$. Thus, the element of $X$ that we have not yet determined can only be $v_i+v_3$ for some $i\in \lbrace 1,2\rbrace$. We can assume $i=1$, since $v_1$ are $v_2$ are interchangeable at this stage, so that $X=\lbrace v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_1+v_2,v_1+v_2+v_3,v_1+v_3 \rbrace$, in which case the change of variables $w_1=v_1,w_2=v_2,w_3=v_1+v_3,w_4=v_4$
shows that $P(7,1)$ holds.
So we can assume that $X$ does not contain $v_1+v_2+v_3$ or $v_1+v_2+v_4$, and thus $X$ only contains vectors of length $\leq 2$.
Suppose that $X$ contains $v_1+v_4$ (or equivalently $v_2+v_4$, since $v_3$ and $v_4$ are interchangeable at this stage). Then $X$ cannot contain $v_1+v_3$ as his would make $X$ have zero sum. Further, we see that $v_2+v_3=v_3+v_4+(v_1+v_2)+(v_1+v_4)$ is outside $X$, so that the only possibility left is $X=\lbrace v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_1+v_2,v_1+v_4,v_2+v_4 \rbrace$, in which case interchanging $v_3$ and $v_4$ shows that $P(7,1)$ holds.
So we can assume that $X$ does not contain $v_1+v_4$ or $v_2+v_4$. The only possibility left is then $X=\lbrace v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_1+v_2,v_1+v_3,v_2+v_3 \rbrace$, in which case $P(7,1)$ holds directly. This finishes the proof of theorem 4.

For the sake of completeness, here is the completed table:
\begin{array}{|c|cc|c|}
\hline
k & a_0(k) & a_-(k) & a(k) \\ \hline
0 & 0      & 1      & 1\\ \hline
1 & 1      & 1      & 2\\ \hline
2 & 1      & 1      & 2\\ \hline
3 & 1      & 2      & 3 \\ \hline
4 & 2      & 3      & 5\\ \hline
5 & 3      & 4     & 7\\ \hline
6 & 4      & 5      & 9\\ \hline
7 & 5      & 6      & 11\\ \hline
8 & 6      & 6      & 12 \\ \hline
\end{array}

A cool answer, +1. I corrected the guessed misprints, please check my edit.

Thank you Ewan.

Ewan, hope you don't mind that I appended the table you completed at the end of your answer.

@AlexRavsky Thx for your help. If I understood correctly, there is an automatic engine here to guess misprints ? I wasn't aware of that

@Colin Tan No problem, thx for the bounty

you are welcome, Ewan.

The following takes a few seconds on my laptop in GAP 4.13.0:
> List([1..8], 
        k->Size(Orbits(ExternalSet(GL(4,2),
                Combinations(Elements(GaloisField(2)^4),k),
                OnSets))));
> [ 2, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 12 ]

These are the values of $a(k)$ for $1\le k\le 8$, which agree with the accepted answer.

This partial answer gives the value of $x$ (resp. $y$), which are the number of equivalence classes of sets of $4$ (resp. 5) nonzero vectors. This answer summarises the discussion I had with Jyrki Lahtonen in the comments. Let $\{i, j,k, \ell \}$ denote the standard basis of ${\mathbb{F}_2}^4$.
Given a subset $S \subseteq {\mathbb{F}_2}^4$, its rank is the dimension of the linear subspace spanned by $S$. The rank of a subset is a linear invariant. Thus
$$a_{-}(k) = a_{-}^0(k) + a_{-}^1(k) + a_{-}^2(k)+a_{-}^3(k)+a_{-}^4(k),$$
where $a^r_{-}(k)$ is the number of linearly equivalence classes of rank-$r$
sets of $k$ nonzero vectors in ${\mathbb{F}_2}^4$.
For $k \ge 4$, a set $S$ of $4$ nonzero vectors has rank at least $3$ since every $2$-dimensional linear subspace of ${\mathbb{F}_2}^4$ contains only $2^2 - 1 = 3 < k$ nonzero vectors. Thus, for $k \ge 4$,
$$a_{-}(k) = a_{-}^3(k) + a_{-}^4(k).$$
When $k = 4$, we have $a_{-}^3(4) = 2$, with representatives $\{i,j, k, i+j\}$, $\{i,j, k, i+j+k\}$. We also have $a_{-}^4(k) = 1$, with respresentative $\{i, j, k, \ell\}$. Therefore
$$a_{-}(4) = 2 + 1 = 3.$$
That is to say, $x = 3$. Together with $a_0(4) = 2$, we get $a(4) = 2 + 3 = 5$.
When $k = 5$, we have $a_{-}^3(5) = 1$, with representative $\mathrm{span}_{\mathbb{F}_2}(i, j, k)\setminus \{0, i, j\}$. We also have $a_{-}^4(5) = 3$, with representatives $\{i, j, k, \ell, i + j\}$, $\{i, j, k, \ell, i + j + k\}$, $\{i, j, k, \ell, i + j + k + \ell\}$. Therefore
$$a_{-}(5) = 1 + 3 = 4.$$
That is to say, $y = 4$. Together with $a_0(5) = a_{-}(4) = x = 3$, we get $a(5) = 3 + 4 = 7$.
So there are only 2 more quantities left to be found, namely $z$ (resp. $w$) the number of equivalence classes of sets of $6$ (resp. 7) nonzero vectors in ${\mathbb{F}_2}^4$.
